# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'instrument' of 'options' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to install jest testing in my visual studio code. I ran into the following errors. Can you please help me with this problem?

● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'instrument' of 'options' as it is undefined.

  at Object.getCacheKey (node_modules/fbjs-scripts/jest/createCacheKeyFunction.js:35:12)
  at ScriptTransformer._getCacheKey (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:280:41)
  at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:351:27)
  at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:588:32)
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:758:40)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:815:19)
```

Comment: Are you using [react-native-calendars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars) in that test by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, this started happening after I upgraded to jest version 27. Pinning its version to `26.6.3`. I.e.: `npm i -D jest@26.6.3` solved the issue.

In case you use typescript and ts-jest use: `npm i -D jest@26.6.3 ts-jest@26.5.5`

Comment: I think this is (potentially) related https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/pull/408

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, after I used version 25 something, it worked. I think there is a problem with a newer version.

Comment: @BadCoder you could accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and managed to resolve it by updating babel-jest:

To fix it, I used the following command:

> yarn add --dev babel-jest @babel/core

I hope this solution proves helpful to you as well.